# Построение гистограммы частоты повторения слов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Нужно построить гистограмму частоты повторения слов в тексте.
Я определил частоту встречаемости каждого слова. Но вот при построение гистограммы столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'kind'
```

Вот код, написанный код:

```
data = pd.read_csv('reutersNLTK.csv')

test = data['text']
test = list(test)

test_string = ' '.join(test)
test_string = test_string.lower()

spec_chars =  '\n,.;><`)(' 
spec_chars

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
text_tokens = word_tokenize(test_string)

text = nltk.Text(text_tokens)
text[:10]

test_string = " ".join([ch for ch in text if ch not in spec_chars])

fdist = FreqDist(text)
print(fdist.most_common(5))
fdist.plot(100, cumulative=False, kind = 'hist')
```

Датафрейм собой представляет 3 столбика. В первом содержиться айди статьи, во втором тема статьи, и в третьем сама статья. Для данной задачи первые два столбика использовать не нужно.

Пример данных из датафрейма:

```
ids categories  text
0   test/14826  ['trade']   ASIAN EXPORTERS FEAR DAMAGE FROM U.S.-JAPAN RI...
1   test/14828  ['grain']   CHINA DAILY SAYS VERMIN EAT 7-12 PCT GRAIN STO...
```

Пример данных с которыми я работаю, после извлечения из датафрейма и обработки на ненужные симбволы:

```
asian exporters fear damage from u.s.-japan rift mounting trade friction 
between the u.s. and japan has raised fears among many of asia 's exporting 
nations that the row could inflict far-reaching economic damage businessmen 
and officials said they told reuter correspondents in asian capitals a u.s. 
move against japan might boost protectionist sentiment in the u.s. and lead 
to curbs on american imports
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: `FreqDist.plot`, если не ошибаюсь, рисует только линейные диаграммы (это обычная оболочка для matplotlib line plot). Чтобы нарисовать гистограмму, советую перевести данные в датафрейм и рисовать уже встроенным методом `pandas` или сразу `matplotlib`/`seaborn`.